# C# DataRow set method

Tags: c#, set, datarow

I would like to ask you about the System.DataTable.DataRow setter method.

My table includes columns of the Id (type int), the Name (type string), Highscore (type System.Nullable). 
I would like to set the highscore field.

If I get the UserRow["High score"] it returns an Object to me.

How can I set the data field?

Comment: Every column returns an object. What kind of Nullable<T> is your highscore column? If it's just an int, `UserRow["High score"] = 300;` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use extension method [SetField](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353039%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
UserRow.SetField<int?>("HighScore", 42);
```